# Magento 2 Development permissions issue

Tags: magento2, permissions

I'm currently developing a Magento 2 site, but I'm having quite a lot of **issues with permissions/ownership.**

I'm running Magento on a VPS, and I have followed Magentos official documentation for multiple users, not shared hosting.

Currently, I have these users:

- root (Web server root)
- user (part of the sudoers file)
- Magento (Magento filesystem user - Is there any way I can double check/change this?) Also part of www-data group
- sftp (My SFTP, locked into /var/www/html)

When I try and upgrade from 2.1.2 to 2.1.3, I get the error :

> Fatal error: Interface 'Psr\Log\LoggerInterface' not found in 
>        /var/www/html/magento/update/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php
>   on line 27

The file in that directory is there, with 775 permissions for `magento:www-data.` I have tried `user:www-data`, `magento:www-data` .. etc.

My Cron job also fails, it only works via CLI if I append sudo before the commend - I believe this is permissions related too. This fails with the error:

> Command line user does not have read and write permissions on
>   var/generation directory.  Please address this issue before using
>   Magento command line." - This has 775 permissions, recursive through
>   the /var/ dir.

I'm using:

- Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS x64
- PHP 7.0.11-1
- MySQL 5.6.33
- Apache/2.4.7

Aside from `chmod 777`, I don't know what else to do. I believe that my Magento 2 isn't using the `Magento` user - how can I check?

Thanks for your time

Comment: What web server are you using?

Comment: @AndréFerraz I'm using Apache/2.4.7, apologies for missing that out

Answer (score 3):

Try fix permissons by commands below

```
sudo find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \; && sudo find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \; && sudo chown -R $USER:www-data . && sudo chmod u+x bin/magento
sudo find var pub/media pub/static -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \;
sudo find var pub/media pub/static -type f -not -name .htaccess -exec chmod g+w {} \;
sudo find -L vendor/bin -type f -exec chmod u+x {} \;
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still having the same issue after running those commands. The file is definitely in the directory, even with 777 permissions owned by magento:www-data or user:www-data I still have the problem - I don't understand

Comment: This fixed my problem